# Validation Rule Issue

Tags: validation

been going around on this. Can anybody spot whats the issue? I'm just trying to get a validation rule to work. Basically, if someone select a certain option in a picklist, I want to make sure that all the fields are populated.

I've tried a couple ways but I've gotten snagged on the

> Error: Field StageName is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

I'll try to use the functions that are recommended in the documentation but I'll run into errors with that too. Can anyone spot the issue?

```
INCLUDES( StageName, "Final Proposal",
OR(
ISBLANK( Geography__c ),
ISBLANK( Languages__c ),
ISBLANK( Customer_Base__c ),
ISBLANK( Number_of_Agents__c ),
ISBLANK( Additional_Resources_Required__c ),
ISBLANK(  Program_Length_In_Months__c  ),
ISPICKVAL(  CRM_List_Requirements__c , 'N3 Provides'),
ISPICKVAL(  CRM_List_Requirements__c , 'Client Provided '),
ISPICKVAL(  Proposed_Commitments__c, 'KPI' ),
ISPICKVAL(  Proposed_Commitments__c, 'Metrics' ),
ISPICKVAL(  Proposed_Commitments__c, 'Results' ),
ISBLANK(  Non_Standard_Program__c  )
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this one:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Final Proposal"),
    OR(
        ISBLANK( Geography__c ),
        ISBLANK( Languages__c ),
        ISBLANK( Customer_Base__c ),
        ISBLANK( Number_of_Agents__c ),
        ISBLANK( Additional_Resources_Required__c ),
        ISBLANK(  Program_Length_In_Months__c  ),
        ISPICKVAL(  CRM_List_Requirements__c , 'N3 Provides'),
        ISPICKVAL(  CRM_List_Requirements__c , 'Client Provided '),
        ISPICKVAL(  Proposed_Commitments__c, 'KPI' ),
        ISPICKVAL(  Proposed_Commitments__c, 'Metrics' ),
        ISPICKVAL(  Proposed_Commitments__c, 'Results' ),
        ISBLANK(  Non_Standard_Program__c  )
    )
)
```

Picklists should be used with `ISPICKVAL` function to check it's value unless it is not a multi-select picklist.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TEXT(StageName)` to retrieve string value out of the Picklist.

Try this:

```
INCLUDES( TEXT(StageName), "Final Proposal", 
OR( ISBLANK( Geography__c ), ISBLANK( Languages__c ), 
ISBLANK( Customer_Base__c ), ISBLANK( Number_of_Agents__c ), 
ISBLANK( Additional_Resources_Required__c ), 
ISBLANK( Program_Length_In_Months__c ), 
ISPICKVAL( CRM_List_Requirements__c , 'N3 Provides'), 
ISPICKVAL( CRM_List_Requirements__c , 'Client Provided '), 
ISPICKVAL( Proposed_Commitments__c, 'KPI' ), 
ISPICKVAL( Proposed_Commitments__c, 'Metrics' ), 
ISPICKVAL( Proposed_Commitments__c, 'Results' ), 
ISBLANK( Non_Standard_Program__c ) ))
```

**Ref:**

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq9SAAS

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that `INCLUDES` is used on multiselect picklists and `Opportunity.stagename` is a simple picklist

```
ISPICKVAL(Stagename,"Final Proposal") , 
...
```

If you need to check StageName against multiple values

```
  OR(ISPICKVAL(StageName,"val1"),
     ISPICKVAL(StageName,"val2")
     ...
 )
```

or sometimes, `CASE` is needed because it uses less formula compiled characters

```
IF ("1" = CASE(StageName,
               "Val1","1",
               "Val2","1",
               "0") &&
... next condition ...
```

Answer (score 1):

StageName is picklist field and when we compare picklist field to a value then we need to use "ISPICKVAL()" function.

```
ISPICKVAL(StageName,"abc")
```